# API Platform Symfony, cannot validate values of type boolean when send sms with sarbacane

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

I created a custom operation to send sms using symfony and sarbacane :

in my `AppUser` entity I added annotations :

```
 *          "GET",
 *          "PUT",
 *          "PATCH",
 *          "DELETE",
 *          "send_sms"={
 *              "method"="POST",
 *              "path"="/app_users/{id}/sms",
 *              "controller"=SmsController::class,
 *              "normalization_context"={"groups"={"user:read"}},
 *              "put"={"validation_groups"={"Default", "sedValidation"}}
 *          }
 *    }
```

In my controller I implements the invoke method :

```php
public function __invoke(AppUser $user, Request $request, SerializerInterface $serializer) : bool
{

    $data = $request->getContent();
    // json decode transforms to object by default
    // add true
    $json_encode = json_decode($data, true);

    $content = $json_encode['content'];

    $currentUser = $this->getUser();

    $currentUserPhone = $currentUser->getPhone();

    $res = $this->sarbacaneApiHelper->call('campaigns/sms', [
        'name' => sprintf("eXpanded n°%s", uniqid()),
        'kind' => 'SMS_NOTIFICATION',
        'smsFrom' => "eXpanded", // entre 3 et 11 caractères alpha-numériques
        'content' => $content, // max 450 caractères
    ]);

    $phone = $currentUserPhone;

    $sarbacaneCampaignId = $res->id;

    // Ajoute des destinataires à la campagne Sarbacane
    $res = $this->sarbacaneApiHelper->call(sprintf('campaigns/%s/recipients', $sarbacaneCampaignId), [
        [
            'phone' => $phone,
        ],
    ]);

    $params = [
        "phone" => $currentUserPhone,
    ];

    $this->sarbacaneApiHelper->call(sprintf('campaigns/%s/send', $sarbacaneCampaignId), $params);

    $sent = true;


    return $sent;
}
```

I tested the api using postman, and I got 500 internal Server Error :

> "hydra:description": "Cannot validate values of type "boolean" automatically. Please provide a constraint."

[image]

Comment: Since the first argument of the `invoke()` method is called `$user` instead of `$data`, it should throw an error. I don't get why not. I don't know what is the `"put"` key within the `send_sms` custom operation. Finally you're declaring a POST operation, it means the `ReadListener` is never called, so the `{id}` parameter is useless.

Comment: thank you for the answer, can you explain what the data should be? what class should i inject to use data, and how can i properly add my custom operation to another route whithout passing id ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why does this error message appear?**

An `invoke()` method [must return either](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/controllers/#creating-custom-operations-and-controllers):

- a `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ResponseResponse` instance,
- an instance of the target entity (seems to be `AppUser` in this case).

In your case, the method returns `true`; since the validation comes right after the controller, Api-Platform try to validate this boolean, and this is not possible. It expects an entity.

**About the showed code within the question**

It remains pretty unclear to me what you're trying to achieve:

- Why the `$user` arg is never used?
- Do you want to save any entity once your e-mail is sent?
- Why do you fetch the `Request` content ?

Comment: thank you, i created a new sms entity and i returned an sms object,  i have one question please, it's possible to expose a class as an api ressource? only a class not an entity, i tried to create a directory in my src, the directory named apiRessource and i created a class and i added annotation to make this class an api ressource, but i can't see the class in the doc of api platform, what can i do ?

Comment: How do you define the difference between a "class and an entity" ?

Comment: an entity will edit database when we execute make:migration and doctrine:migration:migrate, a class will manipulate data without touching the database

Comment: Yes of course, put those class to the `Entity/` directory as well, then remove all `@ORM` annotations from them. You must now either implements your own [data provider](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/data-providers/) or declare a `read = false` [property](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/events/#built-in-event-listeners) within your custom operation declaration. In any case, keep in my mind that your controller must return an instance of the class. If the answer solves your problem, don't forget to accept it.

Comment: thank you so much, si the only way is to remove orm annotation? there's no way to expose a class as an api ressources ?